# string to char array error

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

I want to get this string value to a char array.

The next piece of code contains an error:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      String value = textBox1.Text;
      var arr = value.ToCharArray();

      for (int ctr = 0; ctr < arr.Length; ctr++)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("{0}", arr[ctr]); //arr[ctr] is error
      }
   }    
   catch
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: "... is error" - what error? Always include full error messages.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", arr[ctr]));
```

(`String.Format` was missing)

Note that having `MessageBox.Show` in a loop will be super annoying